# Basis of subspace defined by linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Let $V=span\{ b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space.
Defined on $V$ is a linear functional $\Lambda$.
Let 
$$V_\Lambda:= \{x \in V: \Lambda(x) = 0 \}$$

How can I find a basis of $V_\Lambda$? The orthogonal projection from $P: V \to V_\Lambda$ would help, but in order to find the projection $P$ I need a basis of $V_\Lambda$, which is my original problem.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Is there any additional information you can add to the question? When asked this abstractly, I'm not sure what it would mean to "find a basis of $V_\Lambda$". The kernel of a linear functional could be any subspace of dimension at least $n-1$.

Comment: Take coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in your given basis. Then $V_\Lambda$ is defined by an equation like $\sum \lambda_i x_i = 0$. Solve for $x_n$ (assuming $\lambda_n \neq 0$) to get something like $x_n = -\sum \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_n} x_i$. Can you see from this what the basis for $V_\Lambda$ is?